# How to make TextField and Button equal height in Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have one outlined TextField and a Button, each in a separate grid. I want to make those equal in height.

```
<Grid item container spacing={1} xs={12} alignItems='center'>
    <Grid item xs>
        <TextField
            fullWidth
            label='Enter your e-mail address'
            variant='outlined'
            size='large'
        />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item>
        <Button
            variant='outlined'
            size='large'
        >
            Subscribe
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And I get something like this (after a lot of styling):

[`Image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uJwn.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the InputProps prop on `<TextField />`

```
<TextField
    InputProps={{
       className: classes.input
    }}
    variant="outlined"
    />
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-pn699)

Comment: ```useStyles()``` throws error : ```This expression is not callable. Type 'never' has no call signatures.``` in react v18.2.0 and mui v5.8.6

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69616581/197472