# React Typescript Material-UI useStyles not callable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

For some reason, I cannot call useStyles as it errors out the following:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'never' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
const useStyles: never
```

Here is the full code:

```
import { makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import { ReactComponent as HeaderLogo } from "../../images/logo.svg";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.VampirismBlack.main,
  }
}));

const Header = (): JSX.Element => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Toolbar variant="dense">
        <HeaderLogo width="125" height="75" />
        <IconButton>
          Home
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton>
          Changelog
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton>
          Tutorials
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton>
          Wiki
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton>
          Join Discord
        </IconButton>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  )
}

export default Header;
```

I've built a few different React applications before and never ran into this issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not getting that error, but I'm getting one on `theme.palette.VampirismBlack`.  Have you extended the definition of `Theme` from `@material-ui/core"` to include that color?  If not, you'll want to use a custom theme type and not the one that you imported.

Answer (score 27):

you can solve it by importing from '@mui/styles'

```js
import { makeStyles, createStyles } from '@mui/styles';
```

Comment: Worked like a charm with React/Typescript project. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any workaround for react v18?
Because it seems like '@mui/styles' is not compatible with react v18

Comment: import { makeStyles } from '@mui/material'; for mui 5+

Answer (score 13):

on MU-V5

1. Install the package
   // with npm
   npm install @mui/styles

// with yarn
yarn add @mui/styles

2. Import from '@mui/styles'
   import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
3. Build your code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
});

export default function Hook() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>;
}
```

This should works, it worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

This is deprecated as of V5 Material-UI does not recommended the styles path for material UI. Instead MUI want you to rely on the `sx` attribute with CSS.

Hopes this helps anyone.

The current recommended way
https://mui.com/system/basics/

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

export default function Hook() {
  return (
    <Button
      sx={{
        border: 0,
        borderRadius: 3,
        boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)",
        color: "white",
        height: 48,
        padding: "0 30px",
      }}
    >
      Hook
    </Button>
  );
}
```

This is the reason why: https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/#why-use-muis-styling-solution

---

For info on the `makeStyles` see documentation:
@mui/styles (LEGACY)

On their documentation for styles : https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/

> ⚠️ @mui/styles is the legacy styling solution for MUI. It depends on JSS as a styling solution, which is not used in the @mui/material anymore, deprecated in v5. If you don't want to have both Emotion & JSS in your bundle, please refer to the @mui/system documentation which is the recommended alternative.

Answer (score 8):

The issue was that a newer version of Material-UI is being used.

```
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import { Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import { ReactComponent as HeaderLogo } from "../../images/logo.svg";
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe `makeStyles` is being imported from the wrong package.

This

```
import { makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core";
```

Should be like

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
```

Comment: Also, Are you using 2 versions at the same time? I can see `mui` and `material-ui` packages. Both are separate versions.

Comment: The issue was that I installed the newer version of Material-UI.

Comment: The newer version has moved the useStyle or styled component to legacy package. Do refer the documentation here. https://mui.com/styles/advanced/

Comment: We should not use 2 version of the same library it is bound to cause a lot of conflicts. Do read the migration guide as well. https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/

Answer (score 0):

I have created this hook and works, pretty well.

**useStyles.ts**

```
import {makeStyles, Theme} from "@mui/material";

const styles = (theme: Theme) => {
  return {
    root: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.VampirismBlack.main
    }
  }
};

type StyleType = typeof styles

const useStyles : StyleType = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => (styles(theme)));

export default useStyles;
```

Then, you can use the hook:

```
import useStyles from "./useStyles.ts";
import {useTheme} from "@mui/material";
...
const theme = useTheme();
const classes = useStyles(theme);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, @mui/styles was deprecated with the release of MUI Core v5 in late 2021, [see more](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/).

You'd rather use **[mui system](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/usage/)**.

Using the *sx* prop:

```
<Button sx={{ color: "#232323" }} />
```

Or *styled/style-components* for non-UI components.

Using the styled utility from @mui/material/styles:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
or //import { styled } from '@mui/system';

const MyComponent = styled('div')({
  color: 'darkslategray',
  backgroundColor: 'aliceblue',
  padding: 8,
  borderRadius: 4,
});

export default function BasicUsage() {
  return <MyComponent>Styled div</MyComponent>;
}
```

Using styled-components:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

import * as React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { palette, spacing } from '@mui/system';

const Div = styled.div`
  ${palette}
  ${spacing}
`;

export default function CombiningStyleFunctionsDemo() {
  return (
    <Div color="white" bgcolor="palevioletred" p={1}>
      Styled components
    </Div>
  );
}
```